# Row sum and column sum of a square matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is a real square matrix with all row sums equal to 1 and $A$ commutes with its transpose then show that column sums of $A$ is also equal to 1

I tried to solve using the fact that $A1=1$ where $1$ is the column vector of proper size with all it's entries 1 and using the hypothesis. But couldn't proceed.
Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No other conditions on $A$.. Which is the counterexample?

Comment: presumably $A$ has scalars in $\mathbb R$?

Comment: It is 12th exercise of first chapter here https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.mobt3ath.com/uplode/book/book-32597.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjYyarCgp7nAhVU4jgGHQ7cBMsQFjANegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw3NMStBEpNRuozgQ7h-0pcq&cshid=1579930272552

Comment: @user8675309 Yes. $A$ is a real square matrix.

Comment: so $A^T A = AA^T$ implies $A$ is normal i.e. introducing complex numbers $U^* A U = D = U^*A^* U = U^* A^T U$, with $*$ denoting conjugate transpose.  So $A\mathbf 1 = \mathbf 1$ says that $\mathbf 1$ is an eigenvector for $A$, but based on the above, it necessarily is an eigenvector for $A^* =A^T$   as well, i.e. column sums of $A$ are 1.

Comment: @user8675309 What you wrote seems to imply $A$ is symmetric.  But this doesn't follow.  It looks like you assumed $D=D^*$.

Comment: @ChrisCuster this seems to happen when I quickly do comments.  You are right though it is irrelevant for real eigenvalues, in particular for $\lambda = 1$.  I'll write my comment up as an answer, properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer.

Let $x=A^T1-1$. 
We can show that $x=0$ by showing that $x^Tx=0$. 
Use $A1=1$ and $AA^T=A^TA$.

Comment: This is correct. I gave a full explanation of your answer below.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks:-)

Answer (score 1):

It becomes convenient to introduce complex numbers here.

$A^T A = AA^T = AA^* = A^*A$

so $A$ commutes with its conjugate transpose given by $A^* = A^T$, which means $A$ is normal and thus unitarily diagonalizable. So, selecting unitary matrix $U$, this implies

$U^{-1} A U  =U^* A U = D$
or equivalently
$U^* A  = DU^*$

your problem about row sums being equal to one implies an eigenvector equation, i.e. $A\mathbf 1 = \mathbf 1$.  Your problem then wants you to confirm that $\mathbf 1^T A = \mathbf 1^T$. But this is implied by the above unitary diagonalization.

You may select (/assume WLOG) that $\mathbf u_1 = \mathbf 1$. I.e. the diagonal matrix $D$ is given by
$D = \pmatrix{1 & \mathbf 0^*\\\mathbf0& D_0}$

putting this all together
$\pmatrix{\lambda_1  \mathbf u_1^*  \\*} = \pmatrix{ \mathbf 1^T  \\*} = \pmatrix{1 & \mathbf 0^*\\\mathbf0& D_0}U^* = DU^* = U^* A$

thus
 $\lambda_1 \mathbf u_1^* = 1 \cdot \mathbf 1^T = \mathbf 1^T = \mathbf 1^T A$
i.e. $\mathbf 1$ is a left eigenvector for $A$

Answer (score 1):

Since $A^TA = AA^T$ and $AJ = J$ then
\begin{align}
A(A^TJ)= A^T(AJ) = A^TJ
\end{align}
i.e. $A^TJ$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $1$. This
also means $A^TJ-J$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $1$ or
equivalently, 
\begin{align}
A^TJ-J \in E(1)= \text{Nul}(A-I) = \text{Row}(A-I)^\perp
\end{align}

But, we also know that $A^TJ-J \in \text{Row}(A-I)=\text{Col}(A^T-I)$. Hence it follows $A^TJ-J=0$ which is the desired conclusion.

Comment: Why is $A^\top J - J$ in $\text{Row}(A^\top - I)$?

Comment: @angryavian I made a typo. Earlier, I wrote $\text{Nul}(A-I) = \text{Row}(A^T-I)^\perp$ when it should have been $\text{Nul}(A-I) = \text{Row}(A-I)^\perp$.